# Is it possible to create an 'average' volume from an mp3 file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mp3, normalization

I have been unable to find any kind of library that is capable of creating an average volume of an mp3 file that supports JavaScript on a web client, not in NodeJS.

I need it on a web client as it is a part of a Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of libraries useful when working with sound. "*Volume*" is not a sound property, "*Volume*" is the term used for loudness in consumer electronics, sound has "*Amplitude*".
In digital sounds, it is far more useful to use RMS, that is the average of amplitudes in a sample.
What you want is an average of RMS in a span of time.

Take a look at libraries as [p5.js](https://p5js.org/examples/sound-measuring-amplitude.html) or vanilla JS examples like [this](https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter)